# How to add a 3rd party library in sharepoint 2010 event receiver

Tags: visual-studio, event-receivers, sandbox-solution, assembly-references, third-party-software

I am writing a SharePoint item event receiver to OCR documents that are uploaded/added to a library to generate searchable PDF for that document.  I'm using a third party library (dll) "tesseract.net.sdk" to convert the input pdf to searchable pdf.

I am using visual studio 2015 for sandbox solution deployment to a SharePoint 2010 farm. I have added the external library (dll) using the package external assemblies option but when I try to deploy the project it gives following error:

> Could not load file or assembly `C:\Users\test.user\AppData\Local\Temp\solution-3a181ba8-d203-45c8-8567-c3b0b459ef32\cab\tesseract.dll` or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest."

The exact Windows dll is having a problem with is the `tesseract.dll`.

Please let me know how can I add this dll to my package (wsp) and correct the error I'm encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Open package.package , in the bottom switch to advanced tab. Click add. Below screen will popup. Fill the required details.

[image: Screen]

This way,you can add external assemblies to your wsp.

[This post](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/including-additional-assemblies-wsp-visual-studio-sharepoint-development-tools/) will help to understand more.

Comment: Thanks , But i already tried this way only ...Although i am able to add one external assembly "Patagames.ocr.dll" but as i said  "tesseract.dll" is an naive library so i guess i am facing issue ...

Comment: You faced this issue while adding external assemblies only right ? and you tried adding it the way I suggested,

Comment: Yes , I am adding library in same manner , facing the issue while i am deploying my project (sandbox) to my share point site , as my project have dependencies of two libraries "patagames.ocr.dll" and "tesseract.dll"  and one data folder "tessdata" (contains language cubes/traindata files ) .